# Is inheritance instead of template alias good way to get class template argument deduction to work?

Tags: c++, c++20, template-argument-deduction

I was hoping CTAD would work for alias templates, but it does not. 
I had an idea of using inheritance where derived class constructor is a forwarding one(does nothing beside calling base).

Is this ok solution?

Is there a better solution(my goal is that users do not have to specify types inside <>)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, bool is_mutable>
struct Ptr{
    using PtrT= std::conditional_t<is_mutable, T*, const T*>;
    Ptr(PtrT p): p_(p)
    {

    }
    PtrT Get(){
        return p_;
    }
    PtrT p_;

};
// CTAD does not work
// template<typename T>
// using MutPtr = Ptr<T, true>;

template<typename T>
struct MutPtr : public Ptr<T, true>{
    MutPtr(T* p): Ptr<T, true>(p){}
};


int main()
{
    MutPtr mp(new int{47});
    (*mp.Get())++;
    std::cout << *mp.Get() << std::endl;
}
```

I am using latest MSVC/Clang so I am fine with C++20 only solutions(EDIT: if they are implemented in latest MSVC/Clang).

Comment: IIRC, C++20 added CTAD through alias templates.  Looks like cppreference agrees: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess it is not implemented at the moment... or am I wrong?  https://godbolt.org/z/AYP9ew

Comment: Probably not implemented yet.  C++20 has yet to actually be published yet.  Just trying to let you know in case you can wait for the compilers to "catch up".  It would stink to rewrite the code for only a month later have the feature you need.